# Is my reputation the same in any Stack* communities?

Tags: support

I've been wondering if my reputation in different Stack* community are the same and also if I can get the same badge when posting on Stack Exchange rather than on Stack Overflow.

Thank you.

Comment: Your reputation on that site's meta is the same as that site. But it is what you have earned on the site (except for [the meta of metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)). So 317 on SO could be 317 ***billion*** on [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) if that's what you earned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

Each site in the network has a separate badge list and reputation count for each individual user. The idea being that while you may be 'trusted' with the privileges of Site 1, you may not have the understanding of how Site 2 works, therefore - until you earn some reputation on Site 2 - you will be restricted again from those privileges.

The only difference to this is site association. If you have more than 200 reputation on one site, and create/link another site to the same account, then you will immediately get +100 reputation on all sites you are a member of. This is because it's generally understood that you know how to use the privileges under 100 rep, like commenting and voting.

Further, if you do associate your Stack accounts with one another, then your accounts will all be viewable on your [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) under the Accounts tab. As an example, here are mine:

[image: Robotnik's Stack Accounts]

Your sites can also be viewed in more detail on the [Stack Exchange home site](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts)

---

The only place where your reputation is the same as another site is on that site's specific 'Meta'*. Meta sites exist to discuss the site itself. You are currently viewing Stack Overflow's Meta (which you can tell from the colour scheme and the logo on the top left). If you click on the 'Stack Exchange' menu on the top left of any site, you can use the dropdown to navigate to/from that site's Meta.

<sub>* Note that the Network-wide Meta board [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) **does** have a separate reputation count, just to make things extra confusing :P</sub>

Comment: how about the badges?

Comment: @SecretCoder Their screenshot shows different amounts of badges, so no, they do not carry over.

Comment: @SecretCoder - No, the badges are separate as well.

Comment: In fact the only place I think you can view a combined reputation/badge count is on the combined flair, in the settings on your profile.